# Suggestion for troubleshooting code that returns non-zero values when warranting 0 values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class FoodItem:
    def __init__(self,name,calories,serving_size=0,fat=0,carbs=0,protein=0):
        self.name=name
        self.calories=calories
        self.serving_size=serving_size
        self.fat=fat
        self.carbs=carbs
        self.protein=protein

    @classmethod
    def from_ingredients(cls,name,food_items):
        calories=sum(item.calories for item in food_items)
        serving_size=sum(item.serving_size for item in food_items)
        fat=sum(item.fat for item in food_items)
        carbs=sum(item.carbs for item in food_items)
        protein=sum(item.protein for item in food_items)
        return cls(name,calories,serving_size,fat,carbs,protein)

    def print_properties(self):
        print(f"{self.name}")
        print("--------")
        print(f"Calories: {self.calories}")
        print(f"Serving Size: {self.serving_size}")
        print(f"Fat: {self.fat}")
        print(f"Carbs: {self.carbs}")
        print(f"Protein: {self.protein}")
        print("--------")

#  Name, calories, serving size, fat, carbs, protein: NCS-FCP

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------")

#breakfast items

egg= FoodItem("Egg",72,50,5,0,6)
cheese= FoodItem("Cheese",100,24,7,0,5)
bacon= FoodItem("Bacon",45,8,3,0,3)
green_salsa= FoodItem("Green Salsa",45,8,3,0,3)
corn_tortilla= FoodItem("Corn Tortilla",130,28,5,17,2)
dkb_slice= FoodItem("DKB Slice",110,45,1,22,5)
peanut_butter= FoodItem("Peanut Butter",180,32,13,2,7)
butter=FoodItem("Butter",100,14,11,0,0)
*coffee=FoodItem("Coffee",5,8,0,0,0)*
bacon_grease=FoodItem("Bacon Grease",120,14,12,0,0)
of_oats=FoodItem("Old Fashioned Oats",140,40,2,27,5)

#WF Items and Snacks

wf_oat_protein_bites= FoodItem("WF Oat Protein Bites",160,40,7,23,8)
hu_kitchen_almonds=FoodItem("Hu Kitchen Chocolate Almonds",170,28,14,10,6)
wf_corn_tortilla= FoodItem("Corn Tortilla",130,28,5,17,2)
wf_coco_water=FoodItem("Whole Foods Coconut Water",100,8,0,26,0)
wf_rom_broc=FoodItem("Whole Foods Frozen Romanesco and Cauliflower",50,75,5,15,3)
wf_euro_greens=FoodItem("Whole Foods European Greens Vegetable Blend",90,110,6,8,3)
wf_spinach=FoodItem("Whole Foods Spinach",10,60,0,2,2)
quaker_sns_crisps=FoodItem("Quaker Sweet and Spicy Crisps",140,30,5,21,2)
reeses_mini_cups=FoodItem("Reese\'s Mini Cups",240,28,11,25,4)
pb_mms=FoodItem("Reese\'s Mini Cups",160,28,8,18,4)
protein_shake=FoodItem("Protein Shake",110,12,0,0,25)
fairlife_choc_milk=FoodItem("Chocolate Milk",140,8,5,13,13)

#Fruits

**apple=FoodItem("Apple",95,182,0.3,25,0.5)**
banana=FoodItem("Banana",105,118,0,27,1.3)
melon=FoodItem("Melon",186,552,1,45,4.6)
strawberry=FoodItem("Strawberry",47,144,0.4,11,1)
blueberry=FoodItem("Blueberry",85,148,0.5,21,1.1)
pineapple=FoodItem("Pineapple",83,166,0.2,22,1)

#Drinks

coffee=FoodItem("Coffee",95,182,0.3,25,0.5)
fairlife_choc_milk=FoodItem("Chocolate Milk",140,8,5,13,13)
protein_shake=FoodItem("Protein Shake",110,12,1,1,25)
green_tea=FoodItem("Green Tea",0,0,0,0,0)
diet_dr_pepper=FoodItem("Diet Dr Pepper",0,0,0,0,0)
wf_coco_water=FoodItem("Whole Foods Coconut Water",50,8,0,13,0)

#Meal Prep

fr_salmon=FoodItem("Farm Raised Salmon",300,180,31,0,25)
chkn_rice=FoodItem("Chicken and Rice",400,250,10,30,20)
ribeye=FoodItem("Ribeye",400,220,25,2,32)
sweet_potato=FoodItem("Sweet Potato",150,130,7,24,2)
filet_migon_6oz=FoodItem("Filet Mignon",450,250,30,0,45)
yellow_squash=FoodItem("Yellow Squash",75,170,5,12,3)
striped_bass=FoodItem("Striped Bass",250,170,16,0,26)
white_rice_150g=FoodItem("White Rice",200,150,0.5,45,4)
chkn_thigh_5oz=FoodItem("Chicken Thigh 5 oz",270,140,15,0,25)

#Takeout


print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------")


breakfast=FoodItem.from_ingredients("Breakfast",[coffee])
breakfast.print_properties()

lunch=FoodItem.from_ingredients("Lunch",[coffee])
lunch.print_properties()

dinner=FoodItem.from_ingredients("Dinner",[coffee])
dinner.print_properties()


EOD=FoodItem.from_ingredients("End of Day",[breakfast,lunch,dinner])
EOD.print_properties()
```

I was running my script and I noticed when I set coffee for all three values (breakfast, lunch dinner), I got the macros and calories for the value **apple** for all three values as the output. Coffee has only 5 calories and 0 macros.

Why is the code generating the values for apple? Rather than generating 0's all across the board.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including minimized code, expected output, and actual output. See [ask] for more tips, like how to make a good title.

Comment: BTW, your code's pretty hard to read cause of the lack of spaces. Like, `def from_ingredients` is like a wall of text. For example, this would be better: `butter = FoodItem("Butter", 100, 14, 11, 0, 0)`

Comment: Also yes, make sure to use PEP 8 -- makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 3):

At the end you define:

```py
coffee=FoodItem("Coffee",95,182,0.3,25,0.5)
```

When you have already defined it much higher up.

```py
*coffee=FoodItem("Coffee",5,8,0,0,0)*
```

Now I'm not 100% sure if this is the reason for the wrong output, but I assume it is. Try removing that line down in drinks.

Comment: Hey this is it! Thank you so much dude.